# SSIS Dynamic Excel Destination File Name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

How can I configure a dataflow task that takes data from a MS SQL Server 2008 datasource and puts it in an Excel file where the filename looks like 'date filename'.xls?

Answer (score 3):

Excel is the biggest pain to deal with in SSIS. Usually I store a template file that just has the column headers and nothing else. I start with a task to copy the template file to the processing directory. You can use variables to create the file name in an expression at this point. Alternatively, you can create the file in the dataflow and then rename the file in a step after the data flow. With text files, I have dynamically created the connection in an expression, but Excel seems to be funny about that.

Comment: Thank you for your response- can you provdide a sample please?

Comment: This is the right answer. Working with Excel files in SSIS is like having Israeli and Palestinian diplomats at a table trying to reach a peace agreement. Even if you build the file name dynamically as stated in the most upvoted answer, SSIS still will error out saying that the table (sheetname) does not exist. Ofcourse table name won't exist since we are creating a new file everytime. Anyways, I found this solution, of creating a template and using a File System Task to create a blank copy of the template, and then populate it, to be the safest way to do something like this.

Answer (score 2):

Provided that your column definition don't change.... you can go to

1. Right Click on Excel Connection Manager
2. Expression
3. Select connectionstring
4. bulid expression (for Example : (DT_WSTR, 50) GETDATE() + @[user::FileName]  +".xlsx")

Comment: Could not find Expression on Context Menu for Excel Connection Manager on SSIS VS2008R2

Comment: I get the file output as C:\TestFolder\Test2012-11-07 11:08:25.443000000.xls    By considering variable :@FolderDestination is c:\TestFolder\Test. Is there anyway make it as TimeStamp like FILENAME_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS

Comment: @SarjanWebDev That is correct, it is not available on the Context Menu.  You can find it in the Property Window.  (Just adding the comment for if someone still struggles to find it)

Comment: Simply using an expression for the file name doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Select the properties for Excel Connection Manager instance, Click on the ellipsis for 'Expressions 'property and set an expression for 'ExcelFilePath' to a variable with a valid path to an excel file, this takes cares of the connection string.

You do need a variable valid excel file at the design time, otherwise connection manager does not work, you can overwrite it at run time using a script task to point to the excel file that does not exist at design time.

Answer (score 1):

HLGEM's answer certainly helps. As @sql-rookie requested, I'll provide a sample about how to copy the excel file to a new file named with current date. Hope this will help others with the same question in the future.

Basically you just need to add an additional `File System Task` after the `Data Flow Task`. And use a `variable` for the Destination File Path: `"\\\\file\\"+SUBSTRING((DT_STR,30, 1252) GETDATE(), 1, 10) +".xlsx"`

[image]

[image]